# Layout divided by two buttons (height:50%)

Tags: android, android-layout

Hy guys, i need a layout divided by two buttons. HeightA: 50% - HeightB: 50%.

Like This:
[layout 2 button 50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NoUm.png)

it's possible?? Even with devices of different sizes?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I think I found the solution. I use ConstraintLayout.
I create two button and put a guideline:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sopra"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sotto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

With this solution i can put textview overlaps button.

Comment: please, provide your attempts. this is not a general help center

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:text="A"
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_height` has to be **0dp**. And `fill_parent` has been *deprecated* several years ago.

Comment: @KlingKlang according to their docs, it got renamed so it isnt deprecated

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html - Scroll down to the **Constants** section, please.

Comment: Guys, how is possible use this configuration with relative layout? i try to put a linearlayout for button and relativelayout (to overlaps textView on button), but this doesn't work.

Comment: @scar **NO.** Weights only work in `LinearLayout` and its derivates. But there's something called `PercentRelativeLayout` which allows you to work with percentages.

Comment: @KlingKlang do you recommend this approach? I think I'll have to study ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @scar it depends from case to case.

Comment: @scar you could also ***try*** (to be verified) using a regular RelativeLayout with a centered dummy View (0dp in both dimensions). Then put one of the buttons above it and the other one below it. Both with a height set to `match_parent`. It ***may*** work.

Comment: @KlingKlang interesting is it also works if you put layout_height=wrap_content or even match_parent...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button A"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button B"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:weightSum` is not necessary

Comment: It works, but my question is:
i need to work with RelativeLayout to overlap textView on button. Is this possible with linearlayout?